# Add a new item to a file properties info

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

What I need to do is add a row to a files properties, e.g:
[Example of what the file properties would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYPM4.png)

This would preferably be in python, but Powershell or other windows command lines such as cmd would be fine.

This command returns an error (Powershell):

```
> Set-ItemProperty -Path .\example.txt -Name "custom" -Value "example"

Set-ItemProperty : The property string custom=example does not exist or was 
not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ItemProperty -Path .\example.txt -Name "custom" -Value "example"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (string custom=example:PSNoteProperty) [Set-ItemProperty], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetPropertyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand
```

I'm guessing this is not what it is used for.

*EDIT*
This can get the comments in the version info, maybe I could set it to that?

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path ./example.txt | Get-Member VersionInfo.comments
```

So maybe something like this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "./example.txt" -Name VersionInfo.Comments -Value "test"
```

Comment: For reading and writing binary files, you should use `b` in your `open` call, e.g. `open("test.bin", "wb")`.

Comment: C. Braun, I dont need to edit binary files, I need to add metadata. I know how to add binary data. I need to add non binary meta information to the properties (E.g: Name, Type, File Path, attributes, customMetaInfo)

Comment: _metadata is stored differently for certain files_ so true! There isn't any way we can help you without knowing the type of data you want to modify. As a minimum, tell us what format you are interested in. Then search for information on that format and especially for helper libraries and sample code. Then you may have a good question.

Comment: tdelaney What do you mean by 'type of data' If you mean the file extention, it is .bin. If you mean the metadata info, then it is plaintext

Comment: @Genetical - if its a binary file, you need to access it in binary mode, otherwise python may try to decode the binary parts as utf8 text or expand binary bits as newlines. Also, when adding metadata, you typically need to be able to seek around the file which you can't do in text mode.

Comment: @Genetical - you said a binary file. If its .bin, put that in the question. How are we supposed to know?

Comment: `.bin` isn't a single format.... lots of different software uses it. If its a DVD image for instance, you still need to know what type of DVD format it is. For instance, metadata for a movie is different that a compressed file system.

Comment: @tdelaney The .bin file only contains numbers in binary, nothing else. Check the question, I added my code

Comment: It sounds like you are defining your own binary format. Right now the format seems to be defined as "a single pickled integer" and whoever reads it needs to know that. You could, for instance, expand that to a `dict` that also holds the metadata you want.

Comment: Windows? Alternate datastream ntfs?

Comment: @tdelaney Revised the question to better suit my needs